# Primefaces Breadcrumb tabindex

Tags: primefaces, breadcrumbs, tabindex

i would like to navigate the breadcrumb via Tab-Key

```
<p:breadCrumb>
    <p:menuitem value="Categories" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="Sports" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="Basketball" url="#" />
</p:breadCrumb>
```

in html, primefaces itself creates following code for every item:

```
<li role="menuitem">
<a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#">
<span class="ui-menuitem-text">Sports</span>
</a>
</li>
```

how do i modify the tabindex to make my breadcrumb keyboad accessable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".ui-breadcrumb ul li .ui-menuitem-link").attr("tabindex", 0);
    });
</script>
```